# Why do fungi and bacteria have macroscopically distinct patterns of colonies?

Tags: microbiology

Why do microbes, when incubated on an agar plate forms a distinct kind of appearance i.e., d shape of colony.
 Its kind of less unique in case of bacteria.

Bacterial colony
http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-colonies-of-bacteria-from-sea-water-on-a-petri-dish-agar-plate-isolated-on-black-background-300465722.jpg

Fungal colony
http://textbookofbacteriology.net/penicillium_colonies.jpg
. But if we  consider fungi, an amazing kind of pattern is seen as compared to bacteria.
So, on a broad spectrum if we speak, what is the real or basic motive behind forming these specific shapes. 
Does it serve any purpose in protection or any such particular reason why do they do so?
Even plant leaves do the same. I mean to say every leaf is different from eachother making itself unique..
Why is this particular pattern seen in d universe and what it has to do with the colony of microbes.

Comment: can you give some examples of what you're talking about in the question... for example... "an amazing kind of pattern is seen compared to bacteria" - what exactly do you mean? Can you attach a photo, etc?

Comment: So sorry, its pattern*.

Comment: Fungi have more variable range of colonies as compared to bacteria..tats all i wanted to say in tat particular sentence

Comment: If i directly come to the point, i would ask, why do these microbes possess different kind of colony shapes. What is the primary purpose?

Comment: Plz check the post again i've attached links with respect to the question

Comment: Well the more simplified form of this question would be this:- If we incubate different types of organism on specific medium we see different colonies or patterns for ex- fungi appears different from bacterial colonies in terms of patterns.
Even plants leaves have different symmetrical shapes. So my question is why do different living organism acquire different shape. Do these shape helps in protection  or any other  reason.

Comment: @Ashwin.N  It is about bacteria those are mostly "unicellular".  Whereas fungi, plants and animals are commonly of multicellular clusters.  So, when unicellular free-living bacterial colony on culture  medium forms a specific pattern in colony-development, it is surprising in a different way than multicellulars.